# How to autostart wget when computer starts and internet connection is available in computer?

Tags: batch-file, wget

I am using Windows XP. 
I have created a batch file containing

```
wget -i links.txt --read-timeout=2 -t 0 -w 0 --waitretry=0 -c --no-check-certificate -b
```

and `links.txt` contains the download links of files which I want to download. 
And I put this batch file and `links.txt` in `C:\Documents and Settings\user\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` so that `wget` starts downloading as computer starts.

But my computer takes time to connect to the Internet when it starts and the batch file runs before the Internet gets connected on start-up of my computer and `wget` doesn't download any file and gets terminated.

So my question is, is there any way to run this batch file or trigger `wget` only when the Internet connection is available to my computer? And this should happen only in background, that is silently `wget` should get triggered in background when computer starts and Internet connection is available. If this is possible, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should wait until google returns a ping result and then continue to the WGET command.

The initial timeout command (Vista and higher) will wait for 90 seconds first, so that networking can initialise.

```
@echo off
timeout /t 90 /nobreak
:loop
ping www.google.com |find "TTL=" >nul || goto :loop

wget -i links.txt --read-timeout=2 -t 0 -w 0 --waitretry=0 -c --no-check-certificate -b
```

Comment: thanks........ but still a black dos windows appears when computer starts.....i want to hide this window also

Comment: You can use : `>nul PING localhost -n 90 -w 1000` in place of `timeout /t 90 /nobreak`. `Timeout` don't work on all Windows version

Comment: I did say `Vista and higher` :)  You can replace it with `ping -n 90 localhost >nul`